# Disabling other dropboxes on selection of value in one

Tags: javascript, html, events

I am trying to write a function that will:

- Disable the submit button when no option in a dropbox is selected (ie empty string is   selected). Enable all dropboxes.
- On user selection of an option in a dropbox (that is not the empty
  string), disable all other drop boxes and enable the submit button.

However, as a beginner at JavaScript I have no idea how I would begin this. How would I write such code?

So my simplified HTML would be as follows :

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="confirmation.cshtml">
   <select name="start_to_end_time" class="start_to_end_time">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>

   <select name="start_to_end_time" class="start_to_end_time">
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
   </select>

   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

How can I write code that fulfills this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not a good idea to give two HTML element the same name attribute unless you use brackets [] within it. The last one may overwrite the value of the first one.

JavaScript using MooTools:

```
$$('.start_to_end_time').each(function(element) {
    element.addEvent('click', function(ev) {
        $$('.start_to_end_time').each(function(selectbox) {

                if (element.getProperty('value') != '') {
                    $('button').setProperty('disabled', '');
                    $$('.start_to_end_time').each(function(b) {
                        if (b != element) {
                            b.setProperty('disabled', 'disabled');
                        } else {
                            b.setProperty('disabled', '');
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $('button').setProperty('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $$('.start_to_end_time').each(function(b) {
                        b.setProperty('disabled', '');
                    }
                }
        });
    });
});
```

I didn't test the code. You may define some methods to make it more readable.

Comment: As far as I can see, this code will not seem to work for me : http://jsfiddle.net/3qHhp/ ?

Answer (score 0):

start by loading the button as disabled:

```
   <button id="myButton" type="submit" disabled='disabled'>Submit</button>
```

also, add a onchange listener to your options:

```
    <select onchange="myJSFunction()" name="start_to_end_time" class="start_to_end_time">
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
```

then, write the javascript function:

```
    function myJSFunction(){
     var myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
     myButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
}
```

To check the selected value and disable accordingly (this must be executed in the function called by the onchange method):

```
    var mySelect =document.getElementById('mySelect');
    var mySelectedIndex = mySelect.selectedIndex;
if (mySelectedIndex==0){
    mySelect.setAttribute("disabled","disabled);
```

}

Comment: Thanks for this code and explanation; very helpful in helping me learn. Do you know how I could disable the other dropboxes, and enable them all again if the empty string is selected?

Comment: edited to add the info you need, with some workarounds you'll make it work.